# How do I add a Google Search Console verification meta tag to a read-the-docs page?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I've created a page on read-the-docs that I would like to add in Google inspection for indexing.
https://ltb-symm.readthedocs.io/

In [URL Inspection Tool](https://search.google.com/search-console?action=inspect&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=9012289) explains one way to prove the ownership of the page is to add meta tag in the `<head>` section of your page

I am using sphinx when compiling .rst files into HTML, so I tried to use

```
.. raw:: html 
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="***" />
```

In the `.rst` file, but after compiling it inserts the tag in the body section not the head section.

What to do that sphinx would insert the tag in the head section?

Comment: You don't "put pages on Google."  You make pages available publicly, link to them from somewhere else, and Googlebot crawls them then decides whether or not they should be indexed.  A three week old site is almost never going to get indexed.  New sites need 6 months to a year.

Comment: As far as Google search console verification goes, you should be able to use the meta tag verification.  This  site was having problems initially but reported that the got it ot work.  https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/103508537/google-console-can-t-verify-readthedocs-meta-tags-need-help-to-verify-and-reindex-site?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Search Console isn't going to let you verify a page, it only verifies domains. And you don't own that domain.

Comment: It looks like a subdomain to me, you can verify subdomains